# Java client receiving message from NodeJS server via socket

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

So basically I'm trying to communicate between a Java client and a NodeJS server. Java sends a message via a socket, Node receives it using an event listener, then Node tries to send a response to Java. Something like "OK" because the message was received.

**Java (in Main.java)**

```
try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);

        // Send a message to the server
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        out.write("test");
        out.flush();

        // Receive a message from the server
        InputStream input = s.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

}
```

**NodeJS**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (connection) {

    console.log("Client connected");

    connection.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Request from', connection.remoteAddress, 'port', connection.remotePort);
        console.log(data.toString())
        connection.write("OK");
    });
})

server.listen(6666, () => console.log(`Server is listening...`));
```

The server displays:

```
Server is listening...
Client connected
Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 65025
test
```

but the client is empty, it doesn't get server's response.

I can't figue out where the problem is. I found countless examples for two-way socket communications, but most of them between a client/server written both for Java/NodeJS. Their code was still similar with what I wrote, but doesn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Node.js, but on the Java side, you're invoking `reader.readLine()`, which blocks until it receives a newline character (which doesn't seem to be sent by your Node.js server). On the server side, you'll have to send a newline character after `OK`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've been struggling for too many hours with this, but I didn't expect it to be the cause. Thanks a lot.